# Como evitar el envio de un formulario

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Quiero saber como evitar el envió de un formulario. Lo que necesito es que si la suma de numero2 con numero3 es igual a numero1 se envie el formulario pero si es diferente que se detenga el envio de formulario evitando que se borren los valores en las etiquetas input. Gracias.

```
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
 <title></title>
  </head>
   <body>
    <form>
     <input  type="number" id="numero1" required>
     <input  type="number" id="numero2" required>
     <input  type="number" id="numero3" required>
     <button  type="submit" >Guardar</button>
   </form>
 <script>
     function evitar_envio_formulario() {
     if (numero1 == numero2 + numero3) {
       //Se envia el formulario
     }else {
       //No se envia el formulario
     }
   }
  </script>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera.

Inicias con el botón desactivado, para evitar que se envíe el formulario.

Lo activas solamente cuando la condición se cumpla, escuchando los cambios ocurridos en los inputs.

Hay comentarios en el código.

```js
$(function() {
  //De entrada desactivamos el botón
  $("#btnGuardar").prop("disabled", true);
  
  //Aquí escuchamos los cambios en cada input
  $(".myInput").on("change paste keyup", function() {
    var bolDisabled = true;
    var intUno = parseInt($("#numero1").val());
    var intDos = parseInt($("#numero2").val());
    var intTres = parseInt($("#numero3").val());
    var intTotal = intDos + intTres;

    //Evaluamos  y cambiamos o  no  el estado del botón
    if (intTotal == intUno) {
      bolDisabled = false
    }
    $("#btnGuardar").prop("disabled",bolDisabled);

  });

  $("#btnGuardar").click(function() {
      console.log("Acciones al presionar el botón");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input class="myInput" type="number" id="numero1" required>
  <input class="myInput" type="number" id="numero2" required>
  <input class="myInput" type="number" id="numero3" required>
  <button id="btnGuardar">Guardar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Podés llamar a la función en el evento `onsubmit` del formulario, así:

```
<form onsubmit="evitar_envio_formulario()">
```

Y que la función devuelva `true` o `false` según el caso:

```
function evitar_envio_formulario() {

  var numero1 = document.getElementById('numero1').value;
  var numero2 = document.getElementById('numero2').value;
  var numero3 = document.getElementById('numero3').value;

  if (numero1 == numero2 + numero3) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

}
```